# Transfer Domain and Email Hosting from Godaddy to Office 365 Exchange

Tags: email, office365, exchange-server, godaddy-api

We have our Domain and Email server hosted with Go daddy.

We need to Migrate to Office 365 (outlook).

Go daddy wants to charge us a hefty amount for it. Can a tech-savvy person do it on his own, of yes, where to start from? What blogs videos can help?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

So the question I would be asking is:

1. If you have access to the Goddady Account?
2. Are the emails that are hosted on GoDaddy are the Godaddy Microsoft 365 emails or from Godaddy?

If you do have access to your Godaddy Domain and DNS manager then it would be an easy thing to do.

All you would be required to do is following

1. Create a tenant on Microsoft 365 portal directly
2. Create mailboxes on the new subscription using the default onmicrosoft.com temporarily.
3. Perform an IMAP migration to move the mailbox data. Or user 3rd party migration tools.
4. After the migration, remove your custom domain from your Office 365 plan in GoDaddy.
5. Cancel your Office 365 subscription in GoDaddy.
6. Add and verify your domain in Office 365.
7. Change the user mailboxes from onmicrosoft.com to the verified domain.

Moving DNS takes about up to 48 hours to complete. (Can not receive email)

You can also refer to the following link

[How to Migrate From GoDaddy to Microsoft 365](https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/godaddy-to-office-365-migration/)